# Cropping Images with PHPThumb

Tags: php, imagemagick, gd, phpthumb

[PHPThumb](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/) doesn't have very clear documentation of how to crop images. I HAVE been trying to crop some images to a ratio of **6.6 : 10** i.e I have images which are **1280 by 854**, I don't want the height changed but I want the width reduced so that the ratio comes to 570:854 which is approx **6.6:10** . Then it will be resized normally to about **180:270** which maintains the **6.6:10** ratio.

Here's what I've tried, it hasn't been very successful. Its like the images don't even get cropped.

```
phpThumb.php?src=http://imagedomain.com/image.jpg&sx=0&sy=0&sw=570&sh=854&f=jpg&q=95&h=270&w=";
```

Could anybody point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with PHPThumb, but if you want a really good tutorial which explains how everything works - http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/image-resizing-made-easy-with-php/
I base my thumbnail generator code on this combined with:
http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php#77679
+ extra stuff to handle transparency.

Answer (score 0):

I use the class directly, not the URL call.  On my windows dev box it couldn't find ImageMagick so it was using GD.  I didn't care too much because it was only for dev and not for staging/live. The cropping worked perfectly.

When I deployed the app for staging and found cropping didn't work.  I found that setting the following forced it to use GD, which got cropping to work:

```
$phpThumb->config_prefer_imagemagick = false;
```

Now I only set this when cropping, but leave all the other resizing at the default setting so that ImageMagick is used.